# Creating a secure configuration file that contains passwords

Tags: c++, encryption, configuration

I am developing an application that works with PostgreSQL and other database features that require a username and password to login to the remote server to store the data. The user has to be able to set the username and password which would then be stored in a configuration file on disk. The problem is that anybody can open the configuration file and read the credentials creating a serious security problem.

I have done some research on encrypting the whole configuration file and then de-crypting it when needed, but the problem is that a hacker could put the program though a debugger and easily find out the decryption key. What is the best method to keep configuration data secret on Windows using C/C++?

Comment: "anybody can open the configuration file and read the credentials" Why not setting appropriate permissions? That'd be the standard solution.

Comment: in short: there is no safe way. but you can make the task of the hacker harder.

Comment: @Karoly: This is usually not worth the effort.

Comment: a small effort can make it safe against 99% of the attackers (script kiddies). and yes, for the rest, it's not worth it. they will crack it anyway.

Comment: @NiklasB. Permissions are a nice idea but they can be defeated by booting from a separate OS or obtaining admin privileges (there are tons of privilege escalation exploits for Windows 7).

Comment: @user99545: If an attacker has physical access, all hope is lost. Also, "there are tons of privilege escalation exploits for Windows 7" is just nonsense. I don't know of a single one. If somebody has a 0day, he's got to hate you *very* much to use it against you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment an Attacker is able to attach a debugger to your running program is the moment the game is over. Being able to debug your program means that your user account or the underlying OS is compromised, which means every security measure on your app's behalf is futile. The attacker will (with knowledge, persistence and motivation) know everything you enter into your computer, or have entered and stored before.

Comment: Agreed. What would you suggest I do then? Apply encryption to the configuration file to foil less determined hackers but accept the fact that it will be compromised by those who want to use a debugger?

Comment: Yup. Encrypted config file (or maybe just encrypted sensitive parts in it to keep the utility of a human-readable file) will help against anything less than a debugger, while being reasonably simple to implement.

Comment: @user99545: Don't forget to deny reading permission to anyone except the user... This is even more important than encrypting the file.

Comment: @NiklasB. I beg to disagree - defeating file system permissions is trivial (Google for "Knoppix" or "System Rescue CD"), while defeating encryption is quite a challenge, if the app is not running.

Comment: @NiklasB. "One can easily reverse-engineer the program from a different machine than the one where the configuration file was obtained from." I was worried about that as well, but I guess I will just have to go with the simple encryption + permissions.

Comment: @NiklasB. if you reverse-engineer the app, it will not be run by the intended user, so no user-supplied credentials will be put in. Only debugging while the user is actually using it will expose the nifty details.

Comment: @NiklasB. again I beg to disagree: file system permissions will not help against sniffing on the wire. Actually I don't understand how anything in the app could help against sniffing between DB server and DB client (both not under control of the app)

Comment: @NiklasB. Sorry, we have to agree to disagree, "wrong" and "wrong again" don't motivate me to read further.

Comment: @Eugen: That's not the point. We *have* to assume that a potential attacker doesn't have physical access or any means of intercepting the communication with the DB server. The interesting case is where the attacker has limited user access to the machine. We need to make sure that he can't extract the database configuration from another user. Agreed to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

> The user has to be able to set the username and password which would
>   then be stored in a configuration file on disk

This is the weak spot and this is what you need to change. 
(On a side note, is the password you store **never** going to change? That's another security weak spot.)

As stated in Eugen Rieck's answer, if the attacker has physical access to your system he will, in time, break all your defenses.

The simple solution is clear: don't let him have access to the system that handles security/authorization. Have the SQL server on a dedicated, remote machine and let it handle the username/password validation.

Or, make your app multi tiered with part on a remote machine that handles the user authentication and routs your DB queries.

This will mean that your user will have to login every time they start your application.
(Preferably also after a pre-set period of inactivity.)

It all depends on how safe you need to be. It's important to understand that security is not easy to create and you should always try to use existing frameworks if possible.